# Kafka Connect - Terradata source conector and upserting into Oracle table

Tags: apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

I want to create a data pipeline to read table from Terradata and Upsert into Oracle. Can I use kafka connect teraddata source connector and write to Oracle table using Oracle sink connector.

Answer (score 0):

If Teradata supports JDBC then yes, you can use the JDBCSourceConnector to pull data from Teradata into Kafka, and then the JDBCSinkConnector to stream it into Oracle.